# Using lsqcurvefit, How can I improve the fitting

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, linear-regression, nonlinear-optimization

I need to fit the data given in Runreg.m into the equation given in CalculateTime.m but the value of resnorm is pretty high and I am not able to get good fit.

With the obtained values of A and sigma, if I CalculateTime it is very different from the actual time.

CalculateTime.m

```
function [ Ta] = CalculateTime(par_fit,n)
  T1=484.437812;
  sigma = par_fit(1);
  A= par_fit(2);
  const1= sigma*(T1-T1/(2*A));
  const2= T1/A -T1*sigma/(2*A);
  Ta = n.^(-1)*const1 + const2;
end
```

Runreg.m

```
n=[1.0000      1.5000    2.0000    2.5000    3.0000    4.0000];
Ta=[484.437812 424.2085  382.3534  352.1422  311.6865  253.5879];
plot(n,Ta,'o')
par_fit=[0.8,2];
options = optimset('Display','iter','TolX', 1e-10, 'TolFun', 1e-10, 'MaxFunEvals', 4000, 'MaxIter', 4000);
[x,resnorm,residual]=lsqcurvefit(@CalculateTime,par_fit,n,Ta,[0 1],[1 Inf],options);
hold on
plot(n,CalculateTime(x,n))
hold off
```

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: Just updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably should do first is change `TolX` and `TolFun` to some more reasonable values. Setting them to `1e-100` this doesn't improve the result but just causes more iterations than necessary. I've attached a plot of a result of a fit using `1e-10` for both tolerances. The parameters I get are `sigma=0.9881` and `A=1.0000` and the fit looks quite acceptable. `resnorm` is `483.2636`, which might look high, but remember that it is the sum of the squared residuals, so the average residual is approximately `13`, which seems quite acceptable.

I think what you have to ask yourself is whether `sigma` and `A` are within a plausible range for the parameters you are trying to fit and think a bit more about the problem you are trying to solve. Maybe a few more data points could help to get a better fit? Maybe your initial values or the boundaries for your parameters could be adjusted? In my opinion, lsqcurvefit is doing just what it's supposed to do and your actual problem is something else.

[image: Result of lsqcurvefit]

Comment: I have added more data. fit is good for smaller values of n but the idea is to use this model for larger values of n which it fails certainly. As you mentioned "Maybe your initial values or the boundaries for your parameters could be adjusted" could you explain that.

Comment: I've tried it with more data points, and it seems as if the function you are trying to fit to the data might not accurately describe it. Could you tell us more about the process you are measuring and the equations you are using? My comment about the initial values/boundaries means, that sometimes the result of a fit can depend on the initial parameters when the solver gets stuck in a local minimum, but that's probably not the case here.

Comment: This is the model to predict the execution time on any number of nodes. `tn= σ(T1 −T1/2A)/n + T1/A −T1σ/2A;A < n ≤ 2A − 1` where T1 is the execution time on one node.

Comment: @Harshit: I think that your model might miss some detail. If I understand correctly, A is a measure of the parallelism of a program. You might have to include the cases of ``n<A`` and ``n>2A-1`` as well. As you have implemented it currently, it might well be that the application you are measuring has ``A`` somwhere in a range you are not considering.

Comment: Yes you are correct, the model has equations for those intervals. `tn= (T1 −T1σ/2A)/n +T1σ/2A , 1 ≤ n ≤ A` and `tn =T1/A, n>2A-1` I tried both the equation but the result remains same. regarding `n>2A-1` it cannot be the case here because application scales with increase in number of nodes. We used this model to predict execution time on three other applications which works perfectly. Is there some other way to get better fit. I also tried `fmincon` and results for that also looks same.

Comment: The main problem is A which is between [2-8] for other applications but 1 in case of LeanMD, therefore not able to predict the execution time for higher number of nodes.